# Wildfly 9 address already in use

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, netbeans-8

I created a new webapp in netbeans and tried to deploy it to wildfly 9.0.0 CR2.
I always get this error:

```
18:02:54,246 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:150)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:182)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.HttpListenerService.startListening(HttpListenerService.java:115)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
```

when i check the used ports i see that wildfly uses this ports: 8080,3528,3529,9990. For me it seems like wildfly is blocking itself? 
Anybody an idea?

Comment: Wildfly is running, try check started servers in netbeans, in console, others IDEs and if necessary, restart netbeans. This error normally occur in hotdeploy, when AS restart automatically.

Comment: i have the wildfly plugin installed in netbeans but it not working quite well. It seems like netbeans cannot get the status of the server. If i try to expand the menu of the wildfly server i don´t see any item. I have to manually shut down wildfly. It also happens right after i have started the server

Answer (score 1):

Those having the same problem should check who else uses the port 9990 in your Windows system. [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) is a good tool to find out the guilty of charge. One of possible common causes in this case is NVIDIA Network Service (NvNetworkService.exe). If that's the case just find it in your Windows services list and stop/disable it. The service itself is responsible for checking for Nvidia drivers updates, so any time you want it back just turn it on manually.

Hope this helps and Regards

Answer (score 0):

The Wildfly is configured to use the default port 8080. Most likely, you have another process or service running which is already using port 8080. Try to find out what process it is and stop it, or try configuring Wildfly to use a different port.

Changing port in `standalone.xml`:

One can change the port in the `standalone.xml` file. In the `<socket-binding-group>` tag you will find http related line. From there just change to another port, e.g 8090. Now you will not find that error in your console.

Answer (score 0):

I always had this problem after shutting down my (window) system. Then I [found](https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/) that **windows does not do a full shutdown** but it hibernates its kernel and other stuff. In that scenario my ports were blocked even though they were not used anymore. (so `netstat` with different options didn't show any usage).

To see whether it is this problem do a restart because restarting always fully shuts the system down. It did help in my case so I permanently changed to full shutdown not it is working.

[image: Screenshot showing how to disable fast startup]